# Find $k, m$ so solutions to $(iz+k)^2=-2+2\sqrt3i$ are the same as those to $z^2-2iz+m=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

Given the equation: $(iz+k)^2=-2+2\sqrt3i$ such that the solutions of the equation are
the same solution of the equation: $z^2-2iz+m=0$

Need to find $k,m$.

$z,i\in \mathbb{C}$; $k,m\in \mathbb{R}$

Got messy with the algebra.

Any nice approach here?

Thanks

Comment: You must first identify what all the constants are. Is $z$ a complex number for example? Is $k$ a real number

Comment: $z$ is a complex of course, also $i$ such that $z=x+iy$ the rest are constants

Comment: What about k and m ? Real or complex ?

Comment: sorry they are real

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

If the solutions of following two equations are the same 
$$ax^2+bx+c=0, Ax^2+Bx+C=0$$

then $$\frac aA=\frac bB=\frac cC$$

Comment: @sil, arrange both as Quadratic Equation of $z$ and use the hint

Comment: i thought about using vieta formula but it didn't work. ill try your hint. thanks!

Comment: @sil, yes please do that. Hope you have understood the reason behind the hint.

Comment: not really. i mean it sounds right but don't really know why

Comment: @sil, if $\alpha,\beta$ are the roots of both the equations, what Vieta's formula says?

Comment: they will  have the same sum and product by their parameters

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12144/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-sil)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If you expand the LHS and compare the real and imaginary components you can find what $k$ and $z$ are. If $z$ is a complex number assume that it is equal to $a+bi$. But, the algebra might be a bit long. When you solve the second equation, you can see that $b=1$

I got $k=0$ and $m=-4$

Comment: thanks that's what i did in the first place but the algebra was too long

Comment: It does require some extensive use of algebra but it pays of in the end.

Comment: Nice hint @John. :+)